# increase the size of the pictures taken with android camera

Tags: android, camera, image

I succeded to take a picture using the camera of a SonyEricsson.The picture taken is looking good, normally and for that I've used landscape view ito my activity.

The problem is that the picture taken is not full screen...it ocuppies only 50% of my screen and I can't get it bigger.
Here is how I did it:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.editphoto);
    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
    mSurfaceView.setOnClickListener(this);

    mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    mSurfaceHolder.setFixedSize(getWindow().getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), getWindow().getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());


}
```

And here is my `surfaceChanged()` method:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged");
        if (mPreviewRunning) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }

        Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<Size> sizes = p.getSupportedPictureSizes();

 System.out.println("Lista de parametrii este urmatoarea:"+sizes);
        Size   size = sizes.get(0);
      p.setPreviewSize(640, 480);
      p.setPictureSize(size.width,size.height);
      mCamera.setParameters(p);
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mPreviewRunning = true;
    }
```

I'm trying to obtain a list with all the supported size picture using, using this method:

```
List<Size> sizes = p.getSupportedPictureSizes();
```

which returns the following:

```
[android.hardware.Camera$Size@65d4c50, android.hardware.Camera$Size@65d49ec, android.hardware.Camera$Size@50ddab8, android.hardware.Camera$Size@3fe4e00, android.hardware.Camera$Size@32ea628, android.hardware.Camera$Size@3be67b8, android.hardware.Camera$Size@27ef0c0, android.hardware.Camera$Size@27eefd0, android.hardware.Camera$Size@13f7860, android.hardware.Camera$Size@ef9a20]
```

What I do is loop this list and set up the size of my picture in order to get a bigger size:

```
     Size   size = sizes.get(0);
      p.setPictureSize(size.width,size.height);
```

I've also done: `sizes.get(1)`,`sizes.get(2)`,`sizes.get(3)`.....`sizes.get(8)`.

Now the problem is that when I do:

```
          Size   size = sizes.get(0);
          p.setPictureSize(size.width,size.height);
```

my screen turns black and after a while I get this error in my logcat:

```
WIN DEATH: null
Failed looking up window
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@2b40d510 does not exist
at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8180)
 at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8171)
at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowManagerService.java:7029)
at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:389)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

And when I try :`sizes.get(1)`,`sizes.get(2)`,`sizes.get(3)`.....`sizes.get(8)` it works but my picture looks like this:

http://i53.tinypic.com/2ib2crn.png

So what on earth should I do to get a full screen picture?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the ImageView where I put the picture to have `width=fill_parent` and `height=fill_parent`!